# Changing a password PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a section of code that changes a password in a database upon completion of the following form:

```
<html>
     <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Password Change</title>
     </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Change Password</h1>
   <form method="POST" action="password_change.php">
    <table>
    <tr>
   <td>Enter your UserName</td>
    <td><input type="username" size="10" name="username"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Enter your existing password:</td>
    <td><input type="password" size="10" name="password"></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Enter your new password:</td>
    <td><input type="password" size="10" name="newpassword"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td>Re-enter your new password:</td>
   <td><input type="password" size="10" name="confirmnewpassword"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Update Password">
    </form>
   <p><a href="home.php">Home</a>
   <p><a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
   </body>
    </html>
```

And the the PHP:

```
 <?php
session_start();
include 'dbconfig.php';

$username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $newpassword = $_POST['newpassword'];
        $confirmnewpassword = $_POST['confirmnewpassword'];
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM user_info WHERE 
user_id='$username'");
        if(!$result)
        {
        echo "The username you entered does not exist";
        }
        else if($password!= mysql_result($result, 0))
        {
        echo "You entered an incorrect password";
        }
        if($newpassword=$confirmnewpassword)
        $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE user_info SET password='$newpassword' where 

 user_id='$username'");
        if($sql)
        {
        echo "Congratulations You have successfully changed your password";
        }
       else
        {
       echo "Passwords do not match";
       }
      ?>
```

The problem I have at the moment is when I submit the submit button takes me to a read only page of this code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your script is probably vulnerable to SQL injection. Furthermore, you should not store the password in plain text but rather only a salted hash of it.

Comment: Never ever ever store passwords as plain text! Encrypt, encrypt, encrypt. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html

Comment: Okay, I will add this but this still does not explain why it is displaying this way.

Comment: what's the content of dbconfig.php?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On first looks I can figure out few major mistakes you made:

if you are comparing you should use

```
$newpassword == $confirmnewpassword
```

and not

```
$newpassword=$confirmnewpassword
```

secondly when you use if..elseif... loop format shold be

```
if (condition)
  {
  //code to be executed if condition is true;
  }
else if (condition)
  {
 // code to be executed if condition is true;
 }
else
  {
  //code to be executed if condition is false;
 }
```

You apparently miss the else part in one of your such loops.
Please correct your syntax and try again...

Answer (score 1):

u can 1st select a  table  and check a password  is correct and if correct a   update a  password .else display a error message.hey this  just update a  password if old is  password is match to update a  password...., 
[Cracker World](http://www.crackerworld.in/2013/08/change-password-in-php.html)

```
 $old_password=$_POST['old_password'];
$new_password=$_POST['new_password'];
$con_password=$_POST['con_password'];
$chg_pwd=mysql_query("select * from users where id='1'");
$chg_pwd1=mysql_fetch_array($chg_pwd);
$data_pwd=$chg_pwd1['password'];
if($data_pwd==$old_password){
if($new_password==$con_password){
$update_pwd=mysql_query("update users set password='$new_password' where id='1'");
$change_pwd_error="Update Sucessfully !!!";
}
else{
$change_pwd_error="Your new and Retype Password is not match !!!";
}
}
else
{
$change_pwd_error="Your old password is wrong !!!";
}}
```

Comment: Your code uses obsolete APIs, fails to even *attempt* to hash passwords, and is blatantly vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake here
This `include 'dbconfig.php';`

Should be like this `include ('dbconfig.php');`

Answer (score -1):

After seen your script, i found that you have not use '==' in your password comparison condition.

```
if($newpassword=$confirmnewpassword)
```

Which is wrong. You accepted the birju shah's answer above which is pointing out what i want to say.

Apart from this, i found that you did't use any encryption method, which is extremely wrong. Anyone can hack your password from the database.

You should use Password_verify() and [Password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) functions to encrypt and decrypt your password. These encryption and decryption are considered most safe now days. You should not use md5 encryption because now days anyone can decrypt md5 algorithm.

Here i have made one tutorial [Change password code in PHP](http://www.codeandtuts.com/change-password-code-in-php/). I have covered all the above topics. I Hope that this tutorial will help you.

Cheers,

Comment: you consistently use the wrong terminology. You should hash, NOT encrypt passwords. And equally important to hashing is salting and multiple iterations of hashing, you refer to neither of those, which makes this very bad advice.